# How to serve wwwroot at .NET 5 MVC application in production?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I had a .NET 5 Web API application. Then MVC was added to the project together with `wwwroot` folder and a couple of JavaScript and CSS files.

JavaScript and CSS are shipped by LibMan and minimized to the `temp` by Grunt. The following catalog structure is in use:

```
wwwroot
    css
    js
    lib
    temp
```

Now when running from VS 2019 everything works fine.

However when running binary compiled by Visual Studio from command line at `../bin/Debug/net5.0/` the `wwwroot` is empty in both Release and Debug variants. There are no subcatalogs `css`, `js`, `temp` present in wwwroot. No JavaSript is loaded into Razor pages.

How to ship `wwwroot` with all subfolders and files to a build application?

What is the right way to ship minimized JavaScript and CSS files in .NET 5 ?

The `app.UseStaticFiles();` is called in `Startup.Configure()`.

The _Layout.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/temp/combined.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <environment include="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/temp/combined.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Michael Chudinov,which command line you run?Also,what is your main issue?Could you please explain more clearly?

Comment: I just run a binary compiled by Visual Studio from ../bin/Debug/net5.0/